# Adding custom marker icons to Eclipse margins?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

How do you add custom marker icons (similar to the ones Eclipse already uses for errors, warnings, code folding, etc.) to the margin of an existent source editor in an Eclipse plugin? I had thought there would be many samples on this but cannot seem to find any (or any similar Stackoverflow questions). My goal is to create an Eclipse plugin that provides contextual markers in many source languages.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at defining your own [Resource Markers](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_core_resources_markers.html).  Once you've configured them you generally use builders to manage your Markers, although the API's will work from any Eclipse plug-in.  Try creating a new plugin project with the incremental project builder template (specified on the last new plugin project wizard page) for a code example.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to add my markers to existing file resources without defining my own editor?

Comment: Resource Markers are completely independent of the editors - as long as the editors use the general `TextEditor` framework, which almost all editors do.